# Problems with rpm and rpmbuild in cygwin

Tags: maven, ant, cygwin, rpm, rpmbuild

I just installed cygwin for the first time today, so I'm very new.  During the installation, I included rpm and rpmbuild, as I need these to run my ant script.

However, when I try to run either program from the command line, I get no response, regardless of what input I give it:

```
$ rpm -qa
$
$ rpmbuild
$
```

When I try to run ant with a build.xml file calling rpm, I get something like this:

```
$ ant rpm
Buildfile: [mypath]/build.xml

rpm-prep:
...
[standard prep output]
...
rpm:
     [copy] Copying 4116 files to [mypath]\.rpm\SOURCES\DataTransformation_UI-1.4.0
     [copy] Copied 274 empty directories to 16 empty directories under [mypath]\.rpm\SOURCES\DataTransformation_UI-1.4.0
      [tar] Building tar: [mypath]\.rpm\SOURCES\DataTransformation_UI-1.4.0.tar.gz
     [copy] Copying 1 file to [mypath]\.rpm\SPECS
      [rpm] Building the RPM based on the DataTransformation_UI.spec file
  [rpm] '[cygwinpath]\cygwin\bin\rpmbuild.exe' failed with exit code -1073741819

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 30 seconds
```

Here, [mypath] is the local path where my build.xml file resides, and [cygwinpath] is where I have installed cygwin.

In case you are interested, here is the build.xml file.  Looks pretty standard to me, although I don't use any much either:

```
<project name="DataTransformation_UI" basedir="." default="main">
        <property file="${basedir}/build.properties" />

  <property name="VERSION"        value="3.0.0"/>
  <!-- ============================ RPM Prep Target ======================== -->
  <target name="rpm-prep" description="Set up the local RPM TopDir build environment">
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" failonerror="false">
      <fileset dir="${rpm.TopDir}/"/>
    </delete>
    <mkdir dir="${rpm.TopDir}/"/>
    <mkdir dir="${rpm.TopDir}/BUILD"/>
    <mkdir dir="${rpm.TopDir}/RPMS"/>
    <mkdir dir="${rpm.TopDir}/SOURCES"/>
    <mkdir dir="${rpm.TopDir}/SPECS"/>
    <mkdir dir="${rpm.TopDir}/SRPMS"/>
  </target>

  <!-- ========================= RPM Build Target ======================== -->
  <target name="rpm" depends="rpm-prep" description="Creates Tarball and Builds rpm.">
    <copy todir="${rpm.TopDir}/SOURCES/${rpm.Name}-${rpm.Version}">
      <fileset dir="./" casesensitive="no">
        <include name="*.*"/>
        <include name="**/*"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
    <tar destfile="${rpm.TopDir}/SOURCES/${rpm.Name}-${rpm.Version}.tar.gz"
                                    longfile="gnu" compression="gzip">
          <tarfileset dir="${rpm.TopDir}/SOURCES/${rpm.Name}-${rpm.Version}" prefix="${rpm.Name}-${rpm.Version}">
        <include name="**/**"/>
        <include name="*.*"/>
      </tarfileset>
    </tar>
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" failonerror="false">
        <fileset dir="${rpm.TopDir}/SOURCES/${rpm.Name}-${rpm.Version}"/>
    </delete>
    <copy file="${basedir}/${rpm.Name}.spec" todir="${rpm.TopDir}/SPECS" />
    <rpm specFile="${rpm.Name}.spec" topDir="${rpm.TopDir}" command="-ba --define 'rpmversion ${rpm.Version}' --define 'rpmrelease ${rpm.Release}${rpm.AutoRelease}' 
      --define 'webwarname ${rpm.Web.Warname}' --define 'rpmname ${rpm.Name}'"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ANT issue, the rpm task just calls the underlying OS rpmbuild command.

This looks like an internal error generated by the rpmbuild command. Googling found the following link, which has a comment reporting the same issue.

http://crlog.info/2012/09/11/building-rpms-on-windows/

Comment: It looks like this would work if I were trying to use rpmbuild through Maven.  But if you look close at the ant output, ant seems to be directly referencing the rpmbuild.exe, not rpmbuild or rpmbuild.bat.  It would appear that this works with Maven because Maven just calls rpmbuild, although I can't be sure about that.